# extend the controller class in mvc php project

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

**Goal**

I want to extend my Controller in order to make my code more readable.

**My Code and Example**

So i have a controller with a lot of methods :

```
class teamC extends controller{
  //Index site
  public function index(){}
  //Gets the Basic Info site of the Team Views
  public function info($teamInfo){}
  //Gets to the setting stuff for admins
  public function settings($teamInfo){}
  //Gets the picture site
  public function picutres($teamInfo){}
  //Gets the boards 
  public function boards($teamInfo, $boardID = 0){}
  //New News via Ajax call
  public function newNews(){    }
  //New Comment via Ajax call
  public function newComment(){ }
  //create new Board
  public function newBoard($teamInfo){}
  //Checks what type of member, team members need to be fetched before that!
  private function memberType($userID){}
  //SetUp gets the basic info thats needed for every team page
  private function setUp($teamInfo){}   
}
```

now i want to have, for example, all the methods that only have sth to do with the board in a spereat class that inherits from the class teamC

```
class board extends teamC{
  //Gets the boards 
  public function boards($teamInfo, $boardID = 0){}
  //New News via Ajax call
  public function newNews(){    }
  //New Comment via Ajax call
  public function newComment(){ }
  //create new Board
  public function newBoard($teamInfo){}
  //Checks what type of member, team members need to be fetched before that!
}
```

now when i call a method from the team controller like this: www.mysite.com/team/boards and i want it to call the method from the board class.
Of course it does not work the way i posted in my Example.

**What i have tried/ thought about**

in the route i catch all the methods the are in the, for example boards, and then i create an instance of boards and not of teamC, that works, but it is really ugly and not realy maintainable.

I somehow need to let the teamC know, this method exists, but it is implemented in a child class of yours.

If i cant get this working i just create a extra controller for boards, info, pictures usw...

I hope somebody can help me and point me in the right direction

Comment: This question is some-what more suited to our sister site.  Code Review

Comment: You cant call method 'boards' from team controller becouse it isnt there. I think you dont understand inheritance in OOP. And maybe in this case you should use composition not inheritance?

Comment: I would tend to agree with @Styx If team is not a specialized form or superset of teamC functionality, then why should there be an inheritance relationship?

Comment: because inside the board class i need to access setUp method of teamC class to get the basic data that all of the pages need. 

@Styx what do you mean by "composition" ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: Always remember that inheritance should be used with a `is a` relationship from the child to the parent. Here, is your Board class really a TeamC? is it *really* impossible to make them two separate classes and use them both when you need both, and only one when you need one? If your reason for extending is only "I need methods from class C in class D" it almost certainly is an error to do so. Google about dependency injection :)